# How to zoom into an image, like a platform game

Tags: java, swing, key, jlabel

Hello i'm trying to do a VideoGame so a need make a zoom, but a don't know how to search or what librery of java use to do this. This is a picture of what i want:

[image]

so my window looks like this:

[image]

what i want is when i move the leftKey or RightKey, the wnidow moves to another position like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

well i post a imagen description, because I don't know what kind of background use, i need to know if I need a special background or Graphics component??

well i hope understand my idea

thanks for your answers!

I try this:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 *
 * @author usuario
 */
public class JavaApplication10 extends JFrame {

         int offsetx, offsety; // the upper left corner of your viewport
         Image imagenInterna ;

    public JavaApplication10() throws HeadlessException {

        imagenInterna = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/N/Firefox_wallpaper.png")).getImage();
        setSize(300, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        fr();
    }






    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            JavaApplication10 sd=new JavaApplication10();
        }
    }); 
    }



    public void drawBackground(Graphics g) {
    Dimension size = getSize();
    g.drawImage(imagenInterna, 10, 10, size.width, size.height, 
                offsetx, offsety, offsetx + size.width, offsety + size.height, null);
}

    private void fr() {


        JLabel ff=new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/N/Firefox_wallpaper.png")));
        ff.setBounds(0, 0, ff.getIcon().getIconWidth(), ff.getIcon().getIconHeight());
        add(ff);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code with which you draw the background.

Comment: well i post a imagen description, because I don't know what kind of background use, i need to know if I need a special background or Graphics component??

Answer (score 2):

In the component that draws the background, use the [drawImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) method that allows to specify a viewport, i.e, the sub-region of the full image that you want to draw (and which you call "Window" in your question):

```
int offsetx, offsety; // the upper left corner of your viewport

public void drawBackground(Graphics g) {
    Dimension size = getSize();
    g.drawImage(fullBackgroundImage, 0, 0, size.width, size.height, 
                offsetx, offsety, offsetx + size.width, offsety + size.height, null);
}
```